# Trivial question about set difference: does $B\subseteq A$ imply $B\setminus\{x\}\subseteq A\setminus\{x\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose we have two sets $A$ and $B$ with $B \subseteq A$ does it follow that

$$ B \setminus \{ x \} \subseteq A \setminus \{ x \} $$

I cant find a counter example so i assume this is true in general?

Comment: You might also have a look at [Suppose A,B and C are sets. Prove that if A ⊆ B, then A-C ⊆ B-C](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1988753) or [Prove that if $A\subseteq B$ then $A\setminus C\subseteq B\setminus C$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1170075).
Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24B%20%5Csetminus%20C%5Csubseteq%20A%20%5Csetminus%20C%24&p=1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose $y\in B\setminus\{x\}$. Then $y\in B$ and, since $B\subseteq A$, we have $y\in A$. Further, $y\in B\setminus\{x\}$ implies that $y\neq x$, and so $y\in A\setminus\{x\}$. Therefore, $B\setminus\{x\}\subseteq A\setminus\{x\}$.

Comment: Note that $B\backslash\{x\}$ looks different from $B\setminus\{x\}.$ The latter has spacing appropriate to a binary operation symbol. I edited this answer accordingly.

Comment: That's good to know, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If $b\in B\setminus \lbrace x\rbrace$, then $b\in B$ and $b\neq x$. Since $B$ is a subset of $A$, then we know $b\in A$. So $b\in A$ and $b\neq x$, by definition it follows that $b\in A\setminus \lbrace x\rbrace$.

Answer (score 2):

The statement $B\subseteq A$ means every member of $B$ is a member of $A$. The question is then whether every member of $B\smallsetminus\{x\}$ is a member of $A\smallsetminus\{x\}.$

Suppose $y$ is a member of $B\smallsetminus\{x\}.$ Then $y$ is a member of $B$ and $y\ne x.$ Since $y$ is a member of $B$ and every member of $B$ is a member of $A$, it follows that $y$ is a member of $A.$ And it is still true that $y\ne x.$

Thus every member of $B\smallsetminus\{x\}$ is a member of $A\smallsetminus\{x\}.$

Answer (score 2):

for any two sets $A,B$ the relation $B \subseteq A$ is equivalent to $B \cap A=B$. let $X$ be the complement of $\{x\}$ in $A \cup B \cup \{x\}$, so $A\setminus\{x\} = A \cap X$, and $B\setminus\{x\} = B \cap X$. we have
$$
(A\setminus\{x\})  \cap (B\setminus\{x\}) = ( A \cap X) \cap (B \cap X) = (A \cap B) \cap X = B \cap X = B\setminus\{x\} 
$$
hence
$$
 B\setminus\{x\} \subseteq  A\setminus\{x\} 
$$

Comment: See my comment under the answer posted by "florence". I did the same correction on this answer as on that one.

Comment: thank you Michael. these little typesetting details are elusive!